# mysql datatime column returning null when running this insert command

Tags: mysql

Below is the insert command i am using, and when i run the command it gives OpenDate cannot be null error, but i'm not sure why.  If I switch around the Y-m-d it says invalid format.  I really dont know why i'm getting this error.  The column is DateTime and the DB is InnoDB

```
INSERT INTO tbldealershipcars(Price,
                              OpenDate,
                              `Year`,
                              Make,
                              Model,
                              CarTrim,
                              Miles,
                              DeID,
                              VIN)
   VALUES 
          ('16888',
           STR_TO_DATE('8/12/2011',  '%m-%d-%Y'),
           '2007',
           '87',
           '701',
           '12299',
           '73387',
           'Demo',
           'MyTestID')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date has `/`s and your format has `-`s. They need to match.

Answer (score 0):

> The column is DateTime

Needs to be **Date** if you are only inserting Y-m-d

Or you'll need to change your str_to_date function to include a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
STR_TO_DATE('8/12/2011',  '%m/%d/%Y')
```

or

```
STR_TO_DATE('8-12-2011',  '%m-%d-%Y')
```

[STR_TO_DATE(str,format)](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0280__Date-Time-Functions/STRTODATEstrformat.htm) with all Specifiers.

[Date and Time Functions from dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)